# order by multiple meta_keys?

Tags: post-meta, meta-value

Hi i'd like to order by multiple meta_keys

want to make it order using these keys

adminscore + user_like + _count-views_all + comment_count

combine these keys how should i array order it??

i try this but not work..

```
  $args = array(
            'meta_key' => 'adminscore' + 'user_like' + '_count-views_all' + 'comment_count',
                'numberposts' => $number_posts,
                'post_status' => $post_status,
                'post_type' => $custom_post_type,
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
               );
```

Thanks for check my question, hope someone has answer for it.

Comment: Are you adding up the values?

Comment: yes.. i like to add up values and orderby from it.

Comment: Then you need to add the values and store it as a separate meta. Then use it for ordering. Check the @Syamil MJ's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
'meta_key' => 'adminscore' + 'user_like' + '_count-views_all' + 'comment_count',
```

`'meta_key'` only accepts string value.

What you need is an additional meta key, e.g. "totalscore" that holds the total value of the scores you have for all the meta values. You can manually run a php function that calculates and store the totalscore value from time to time or use [wp_schedule_event](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) to run the function on a set interval.

You can then write the $args as such:

```
$args = array(
            'meta_key' => 'totalscore',
            'numberposts' => $number_posts,
            'post_status' => $post_status,
            'post_type' => $custom_post_type,
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
);
```

Comment: Exactly. Plus one.

Comment: Hi, Syamil thanks for solve my question. the 'wp_schedule_event' could be a way that solve this problem. where should I locate the code? in function.php? and..
could you make any sample code to save new meta value(totalscore) from add up meta values such as view count, user_like_ comment_count using the 'wp_schedule_event'.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do here is to use the [`posts_orderby` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby)

To make sure you don't modify any other queries, use the `add_filter` call just before retrieving the posts & a `remove_filter` call either in the hooked function itself or just after you have the posts.

Comment: Hi, Mridul thanks for answering. i don't under stand using filter.. do you have any code example?;

Comment: The link in the answer already has an example to get you started. For a more complete reference, you can go through [this codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API)